# Calculate $\frac{1}{\sin(x)} +\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ if $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\frac{7}{5}$

Tags: trigonometry

If

\begin{equation}
  \sin(x) + \cos(x) = \frac{7}{5},
\end{equation}

then what's the value of

\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{\sin(x)} + \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\text{?}
\end{equation}

Meaning the value of $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ (the denominator) without using the identities of trigonometry.

The function $\sin x+\cos x$ could be transformed using some [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) to a single function. In fact, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(x)%2Bcos(x)) says it is equal to $\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)$ and there also are some posts on this site [about this equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597209/sin-x-cos-x-sqrt2-sin-x-pi-over4). So probably in this way we could calculate $x$ from the first equation - and once we know $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, we can calculate $\dfrac{1}{\sin x}+\dfrac{1}{\cos x}$. Is there a simpler solution (perhaps avoiding explicitly finding $x$)?

Comment: Note: $ \sin x+ \cos x = \sqrt2\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$

Comment: It is impossible without identities.

Comment: my hint: $(\sin x+\cos x)^2=1+2\sin x\cosx$

Comment: If this is the sort of post that ends up becoming a HNQ, I think it really, really demeans this site.  The entire SE network can just click on the HNQ, and assume this question, and it's answers which are easily  found via Wolfram Alpha, represent this sites quality.  In this case, not at all.

Answer (score 105):

Notice, $$\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}$$
$$=\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x\cos x}$$
$$=2\cdot \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{2\sin x\cos x}$$
$$=2\cdot \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2-1}$$
setting the value of $\sin x+\cos x$, 
$$=2\cdot \frac{\frac 75}{\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{35}{12}$$

Comment: thanks mate , that was pretty easy

Comment: You used the trigonometric identity $sin^(x)+cos^2(x)=1$

Comment: 100 up votes :)

Comment: Just wondering ...  Suppose we let $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=a$ then we'll get $$\frac{1}{\cos(x)}+\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=2\cdot\frac{a}{a^2-1},$$ even if $a=10$, say?

Comment: No. It is valid only for $-\sqrt{2}\le \sin x+\cos x\le \sqrt{2}$ . Therefore the range of $a$ must be $-\sqrt{2}\le a\le \sqrt{2}$. Hence the formula: $\dfrac{1}{\cos x}+\dfrac{1}{\sin x}=2\cdot \dfrac{a}{a^2-1}$ is not valid for $a=10$

Answer (score 19):

$$\sin x+\cos x=\frac{7}{5}$$
Let  $\sin x=t$
$$\implies t+\sqrt{1-t^2}=\frac{7}{5}$$
Shifting, squaring and simplifying, we get
$$25t^2-35t+12=0$$
$$\implies t=\frac{35 \pm 5}{50}$$
Hence, $$\sin x= \frac{4}{5},\ \cos x=\frac{3}{5} \ \text{or} \ \cos x= \frac{4}{5}, \ \sin x=\frac{3}{5}$$
But as we need to find $$\frac{1}{\sin(x)}  +\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$ it becomes
$$\frac{5}{4}+\frac{5}{3}=\frac{35}{12}$$

Answer (score 18):

\begin{align}
  \sin(x)+\cos(x) &= \frac 75 \\
  \left(\sin(x)+\cos(x)\right)^2 &= \left( \frac 75 \right)^2 \\
  1 + 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) &= \frac{49}{25} \\
  \sin(x) \cos(x) &= \frac{12}{25}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{\sin(x)}  + \frac{1}{\cos(x)}
  &= \frac{\sin(x)  + \cos(x)}{\sin(x) \cos(x)}\\
  &= \frac{\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)}{\left(\frac{12}{25}\right)}\\
&= \frac{7 \times 25}{5\times 12}\\
  &= \frac{35}{12}
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\frac75
&\implies1-\sin^2(x)=\frac{49}{25}-\frac{14}5\sin(x)+\sin^2(x)\\
&\implies\sin^2(x)-\frac75\sin(x)+\frac{12}{25}=0\\
&\implies\sin(x)=\frac{7\pm1}{10}\\
&\implies\sin(x)\in\left\{\frac35,\frac45\right\}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\cos(x)=\frac75-\sin(x)\gt0$, if $\sin(x)=\frac35$ then $\cos(x)=\frac45$ and vice-versa. Therefore,
$$
\frac1{\sin(x)}+\frac1{\cos(x)}=\frac{35}{12}
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$ s + c = \frac{7}{5};\quad  s^2 + c^2 \frac{35}{12} = 1; $$

Solving quadratic equation by elimination of one of the two variables

$$ s= \left(\frac{4}{5}, \frac{3}{5} \right );\quad c = \left(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5} \right) ; $$

respectively. They are interchangeable. So only one result is obtained with either of two inputs:

$$ \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{c} =\frac{5}{4} +\frac{5}{3} = \frac{35}{12}. $$

Answer (score 3):

If

$$\sin x+\cos x=a\qquad\text{and}\qquad{\frac{1}{\sin x}}+{\frac{1}{\cos x}}=b$$ then

$$a=b\sin x\cos x\qquad\text{and}\qquad a^2=1+2\sin x\cos x=1+\frac{2a}{b}$$

from which it follows that

$$b={\frac{2a}{a^2-1}}$$

Letting $a=\frac{7}{5}$, we have

$$b={\frac{\frac{14}{5}}{\frac{49}{25}-1}}={\frac{70}{24}}={\frac{35}{12}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Assume that,

$\sin x=a, \cos x=b $

Given that : $$\sin x+\cos x=\frac75$$ 
$$a+b=\frac75\tag 1$$ 
$$\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$$ 
$$a^2 +b^2 =1$$ 
$$(a+b)^2-2ab =1$$ 
$$(7/5)^2-2ab =1$$ 
$$ab=12/25\tag 2$$ 
solving (1), (2), i get $a=3/5, b=4/5$
therefore,
$$\frac1{\sin x}+\frac1{\cos x}=\frac1a+\frac1b$$$$=\frac{1}{3/5}+\frac{1}{4/5}$$ $$=\frac{35}{12}$$

Answer (score 2):

initially i  have

$\sin x+\cos x={7\over5}$

took the squares,

$\sin^2x+\cos^2x+2\sin x\cos x={49\over 25}$

$1+2\sin x\cos x={49\over 25}$

$\sin x\cos x={49\over 50}-{1\over 2}={12\over 25}$

$$\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}$$
$$\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x\cos x}$$
$$\frac{{7\over 5}}{{12\over 25}}$$
$${35\over 12}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x+\cos x=\frac75\tag1$$
take the squares,
$$(\sin x+\cos x)^2=\left(\dfrac75\right)^2$$
$$\sin x\cos x=\frac{12}{25}\tag2$$
$$\therefore \dfrac{1}{\sin x}+\dfrac{1}{\cos x}$$
$$=\dfrac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x\cos x}$$
$$=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{7}{5}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{12}{25}\right)}$$
$$=\dfrac{35}{12}$$
Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Comment: I answered it in my own way.

Answer (score 1):

$$ x+y= p\tag1$$
Square, since $( x^2+y^2=1 )$
$$ 1+ 2 x\;y = p^2, \; x y= \dfrac{p^2-1}{2} \tag2$$
From (1) and (2)
$$ \dfrac{1}{x}+  \dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{x+y}{x y}=  \dfrac{2p}{p^2-1} $$
$$ = \dfrac{35}{12},\;$$
if
$$\;p= \dfrac{7}{5} $$

Comment: Approved your nice solution. +1.